# Deciding convergence/divergence of $\sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{m^3} \sum\limits_{\substack{k=1\\(m,k) = 1}}^m k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k n}{m}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum

Let $n$ be a positive integer. I am attempting to determine whether the series
$$
\sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{m^3} \sum_{\substack{k=1\\(m,k) = 1}}^m k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k n}{m}\right)
$$
converges or diverges. I've tried the (admittedly naive) bound $|k\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{m}\right)| < k$, but this doesn't help:
$$
\sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{m^3} \sum_{\substack{k=1\\(m,k) = 1}}^m k \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k n}{m}\right) < \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{m^3} \sum_{\substack{k=1\\(m,k) = 1}}^m k \left|\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k n}{m}\right)\right| < \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^3} m\sum_{\substack{k=1\\(m,k) = 1}}^m 1 = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\varphi(m)}{m^2} = \infty,
$$
where $\varphi$ is the totient function. I've also try leveraging the fact that
$$
\sum_{\substack{k=1\\(m,k) = 1}}^m \sin\left(\frac{2\pi kn}{m}\right) = 0,
$$
but that too led to a dead end. Is there an obvious trick to determine whether this series converges or diverges?

Comment: Have you considered the case where $m$ is prime? Maybe you can get a lower bound which diverges

Comment: The terms are not all nonnegative, so that's probably harder than it sounds.

Comment: When $m$ is prime you can estimate it asymptotically (Riemann sum) which can be used to show that the sum doesn't converge absolutely. So estimates like you tried (relying on bounding the absolute value) won't get you anywhere here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This series **diverges**.

Assuming $n>0$ fixed, let $$a_m=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant m\\(k,m)=1}}k\sin\frac{2nk\pi}{m},\quad b_m=\sum_{1\leqslant k\leqslant m}k\sin\frac{2nk\pi}{m}.$$ If $m\nmid n$ and $\omega=e^{2n\pi\mathrm{i}/m}$, then $(\omega-1)\sum_{k=1}^m k\omega^k=m\omega^{m+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\omega^k=m\omega$, hence $$b_m=\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\sum_{k=1}^{m}k(\omega^k-\omega^{-k})=\frac{m}{2\mathrm{i}}\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega-1}-\frac{\omega^{-1}}{\omega^{-1}-1}\right)=-\frac{m}{2}\cot\frac{n\pi}{m},$$ and trivially $b_m=0$ if $m\mid n$.

Further, for $d\mid m$, we have $$a_{m,d}:=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant m\\(k,m)=\color{red}{d}}}k\sin\frac{2nk\pi}{m}=\sum_{\substack{1\leqslant k\leqslant m/d\\(k,m/d)=1}}kd\sin\frac{2nkd\pi}{m}=da_{m/d}$$ and clearly $$b_m=\sum_{d\mid m}a_{m,d}=\sum_{d\mid m}da_{m/d}=\sum_{d\mid m}(m/d)a_d\implies\frac{b_m}{m}=\sum_{d\mid m}\frac{a_d}{d}.$$

By [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), and our computation of $b_m$ above, $$\frac{a_m}{m}=\sum_{d\mid m}\mu\Big(\frac{m}{d}\Big)\frac{b_d}{d}=-\frac12\sum_{d\mid m,\ d\nmid n}\mu\Big(\frac{m}{d}\Big)\cot\frac{n\pi}{d}=\frac12(A_m-B_m),\\A_m:=\sum_{d\mid m,\ d\nmid n}\mu\Big(\frac{m}{d}\Big)\left(\frac{d}{n\pi}-\cot\frac{n\pi}{d}\right),\\B_m:=\frac{1}{n\pi}\sum_{d\mid m,\ d\nmid n}d\mu(m/d)=\frac{1}{n\pi}\left(\varphi(m)-\sum_{d\mid(m,n)}d\mu(m/d)\right).$$

To estimate $A_m$, denote $f(x)=(1/x)-\cot x$; then $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x\to 0$. Now we split $A_m$ into a sum over $d<2n$, which is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ as $m\to\infty$, and a sum over $d\geqslant 2n$, which is at most $$\sum_{d=2n}^{m}f\left(\frac{n\pi}{d}\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{d=1}^{m}\frac1d\right)=\mathcal{O}(\log m)$$ in absolute value; hence, $A_m=\mathcal{O}(\log m)$ as $m\to\infty$, and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty A_m/m^2$ converges.

But $\sum_{m=1}^\infty B_m/m^2$ diverges, since $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\varphi(m)/m^2$ does, and $\sum_{d\mid(m,n)}d\mu(m/d)=\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how $A_m$ is $\mathcal{O}(\log m)$? I don't see how this follows from $(1/x) - \cot x = \mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @fruitegg: edited it in.